# UnsupportedOperationException when using RichFunction in WindowedStream.fold()

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

How can I use a `RichFoldFunction` in the `WindowedStream.fold()` method?

It always throws:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:: FoldFunction can not be a RichFunction. Please use fold(FoldFunction, WindowFunction) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you read this [mailing list thread](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/FoldFunction-accumulator-checkpointing-td6068.html) for an explanation of why this hasn't been allowed.

However, depending on what you are trying to do, [ProcessWindowFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/windows.html#processwindowfunction), which is coming soon in Flink 1.3, might provide a solution.